# ocaml Error: This expression has type expr but is here used with type unit -> expr

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I can't figure out what this error means, I've never seen if before
the line it is complaining about is the line that contains  x -> let
I was using match with before this but it was still giving me the same error.

```
let rec build (rand,depth) = match depth with
 | 0 -> if rand(0,2) == 0 then buildX else buildY
 | x -> let r =  rand(0, 5) in
     if r == 0 then buildSine (build (rand, x -1))
     else if r == 1 then buildCosine (build (rand, x -1))
     else if r == 2 then buildAverage (build (rand,x -1), build (rand,x-1))
     else if r == 3 then buildTimes (build (rand, x -1), build (rand, x-1))
     else buildThresh (build(rand, x-1), build(rand, x-1),               
                   build(rand, x-1), build(rand, x-1));;
```

each of my the builds returns a expr and this is supposed to build one big expr
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: without the definitions, or at least the declarations of all the bindings in your code snippet, it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `buildX` and `buildY` are supposed to take an argument?

```
# let f () = 14;;
val f : unit -> int = <fun>
# f ;;
- : unit -> int = <fun>
# f ();;
- : int = 14
```

Comment: They aren't :/ it has empty ()

Comment: In OCaml, empty () is a value.

Comment: I guess @JeffreyScofield found out.

Comment: Thanks alot >.< i'm still noob at ocaml haha